# Creation of tables in Oracle db from Java

Tags: java, oracle

I have a situation where I need to create/alter a table (External Table) in Oracle every time I get the data in files. Since the number of data files keep changing I need to modify the "location" property of the external  table. 
I use this table to update many other tables in the database.

Will the creating/altering  the table at run time
be of any help performance wise or rather will it hurt the performance of
the code?

P.S: The performance I am looking here the time taken to update the other tables by accessing this external table.

Comment: why not change the files names ? why the table's location ?

Comment: If i am not wrong the names of the files are mentioned in the location property in external table. I was trying to tell that i need to alter the location property where the names of the files are entered. If i do that every time i get different number of files as output of java. I have to keep altering the table. 
how good will this approach be when compared to keeping the number of files intact?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might depend on many things.
One major thing may be the number of files and the amount of parallelism you can aford. Basically, External tables can read all source [files in parallel](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm#i1007483), if this is your case then I'd think that it's not worth altering the table every time.
Another thing may be the span between the max amount of files and the min...